# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask and I'm not able to find what is the mistake

Tags: java, android, soap

I'm a beginner in developing android app, and I didn't find any mistake in my code but after executing the thread in onPostExecute() method

```
public class closingBalance extends ActionBarActivity {


    private String fp_shop;
    private String cb;
    private int i = 0;
    Bundle bundle;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    EditText Rice_cb, Tumeric_cb, Kerosene_cb, Atta_cb, Wheat_cb, Sugar_cb, Salt_cb, Chilli_cb, Palmolein_cb, Redgram_cb;
    TextView closingbalancereport;
    private String RiceCB;
    private String SugarCB;
    private String WheatCB;
    private String AttaCB;
    private String KeroseneCB;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_closing_balance);

        Rice_cb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rice);
        Tumeric_cb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tumeric);
        Palmolein_cb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Palmolein);
        Redgram_cb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Redgram);
        Chilli_cb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Chilli);
        Salt_cb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Salt);
        Sugar_cb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Sugar);
        Wheat_cb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Wheat);
        Atta_cb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Atta);
        Kerosene_cb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Kerosene);
        closingbalancereport = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shopNoandName);


        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(closingBalance.this);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(closingBalance.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Processing Data...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
//        progressDialog.show();

        new SoapAccessTask().execute();


    }

    private class SoapAccessTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Vector<SoapObject>> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            fp_shop = bundle.getString("fp_shop");

            closingbalancereport.setText("Closing Balance Report");
            closingbalancereport.setSelected(true);


        }

        @Override
        protected Vector<SoapObject> doInBackground(String... params) {

            Vector<SoapObject> soapObject = WebService.getClosingBal(fp_shop);
//            System.out.println("response in CB activity : " + soapObject);
            onPostExecute(soapObject);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Vector<SoapObject> soapObject) {
            super.onPostExecute(soapObject);
             final Vector<SoapObject> object = soapObject;
            System.out.println("response in CB activity on Post execute  :" + soapObject);



                closingBalance.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        System.out.println("thread started");
                        for (SoapObject cs : object) {
                            System.out.println("property " + cs + " :" + object.get(i++));
                            for (int j = 0; j < cs.getPropertyCount(); j++) {
                                PropertyInfo info = new PropertyInfo();
                                cs.getPropertyInfo(j, info);
                                System.out.println("package properties " + j + "- " + info.name + " : " + cs.getProperty(j));
                                if (info.name.contains("closing_balance")) {
                                    cb = info.getValue().toString();
                                }
                                if (info.name.contains("comm_name") && info.getValue().toString().contains("Rice")) {
                                    if (cb == null)
                                        Rice_cb.setText("NA");
                                    else
                                        Rice_cb.setText(cb);
                                }
                                if (info.name.contains("comm_name") && info.getValue().toString().contains("Sugar")) {
                                    if (cb == null)
                                        Sugar_cb.setText("NA");
                                    else
                                        Sugar_cb.setText(cb);
                                }
                                if (info.name.contains("comm_name") && info.getValue().toString().contains("Wheat")) {
                                    if (cb == null)
                                        Wheat_cb.setText("NA");
                                    else
                                        Wheat_cb.setText(cb);
                                }
                                if (info.name.contains("comm_name") && info.getValue().toString().contains("whole Meal Atta")) {
                                    if (cb == null)
                                        Atta_cb.setText("NA");
                                    else
                                        Atta_cb.setText(cb);
                                }
                                if (info.name.contains("comm_name") && info.getValue().toString().contains("Kerosene Oil")) {
                                    if (cb == null)
                                        Kerosene_cb.setText("NA");
                                    else
                                        Kerosene_cb.setText(cb);
                                }
                                if (info.name.contains("comm_name") && info.getValue().toString().contains("Kerosene Oil")) {
                                    if (cb == null)
                                        Kerosene_cb.setText("NA");
                                    else
                                        Kerosene_cb.setText(cb);
                                }


//                    if(info.name.contains("comm_name") && info.getValue().toString().contains("Turmeric Powder")){
//                        if(cb == null || cb.isEmpty())
                                Tumeric_cb.setText("NA");
                                Palmolein_cb.setText("NA");
//                        else
//                            Tumeric_cb.setText(cb);
//                    }
//                    if(info.name.contains("comm_name") && info.getValue().toString().contains("Redgram Dal")){
//                        if(cb == null || cb.isEmpty())
                                Redgram_cb.setText("NA");
//                        else
//                            Redgram_cb.setText(cb);
//                    }
//                    if(info.name.contains("comm_name") && info.getValue().toString().contains("Redgram Dal")){
//                        if(cb == null || cb.isEmpty())
                                Redgram_cb.setText("NA");
//                        else
//                            Redgram_cb.setText(cb);
//                    }
//                    if(info.name.contains("comm_name") && info.getValue().toString().contains("Chilli Powder")){
//                        if(cb == null || cb.isEmpty())
                                Chilli_cb.setText("NA");
//                        else
//                            Chilli_cb.setText(cb);
//                    }
//                    if(info.name.contains("comm_name") && info.getValue().toString().contains("Salt")){
//                        if(cb == null || cb.isEmpty() && info.name.contains("comm_name"))
                                Salt_cb.setText("NA");
//                        else
//                            Salt_cb.setText(cb);
                            }


                        }
                    }

                });
            Thread.currentThread().start();



        }
    }
}
```

I see this in my LogCat

```
05-21 15:57:21.936    2051-2188/com.example.nic_scm E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.nic_scm, PID: 2051
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started
            at java.lang.Thread.checkNotStarted(Thread.java:849)
            at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1059)
            at com.example.nic_scm.closingBalance$SoapAccessTask.onPostExecute(closingBalance.java:200)
            at com.example.nic_scm.closingBalance$SoapAccessTask.doInBackground(closingBalance.java:98)
            at com.example.nic_scm.closingBalance$SoapAccessTask.doInBackground(closingBalance.java:77)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: No need to use `Thread.currentThread().start();` and `closingBalance.this.runOnUiThread` in `onPostExecute` method  line just comment it then try to run application

Comment: Do not call onPostExecute(soapObject); in yourdoInBackground(), this will be done automatically. And add @Override to your onPostExecute()

Comment: Go through [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) link.

Comment: start ProgressDialog in onPreExecute.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK  I tried doing it without using runOnUiThread in OnPostExecute() but it didn't resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove  `Thread.currentThread().start();`. `execute()` takes care of starting the AsyncTask's thread. And you can't call start on the same instance twice. Also, not related to the exception, get rid of

```
 onPostExecute(soapObject);
 progressDialog.dismiss();
```

from `doInBackground`. `onPostExecute` is called by android when doInBackground returns, and doInBackground is not allowed to touch the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check state of thread before starting

```
if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
{
    Thread.currentThread().start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the `onPostExecute` it will be automatically called.
- dismiss() is a UI related work so it should not called from the background thread.

  ```
  @Override
  protected Vector<SoapObject> doInBackground(String... params) {

      Vector<SoapObject> soapObject = WebService.getClosingBal(fp_shop);
      return null;
  }
  ```